# AngularJS : How to inject a service into a factory

Tags: angularjs, promise, factory, angular-resource

I have a REST backend which provides a hashmap of API methods.  This allows the front end to use a keyname to map to the API method instead of needing to know the entire REST url.

Ex:

```
{
  CHARGE.GET_CHARGE_INFO: /provider/charge/getChargeInfo/{{providerId}}/{{chargeId}}
  CHARGE.LIST_CHARGES: /provider/charge/listCharges/{{providerId}}
  CHARGE.LIST_TYPES: /provider/charge/listTypes
}
```

There is a service which is responsible for loading the hashmap from the REST API.

```
app.service('preloader', function ($http, globals, $interpolate, $q) {
    var self = this;
    var endPointsList = $http.get(globals.apiPath + globals.endPointsPath, {}).success(function (data) {
        self.endPoints = data;
    });

    return {
        endPointsList: endPointsList,
        getResourceEndPoint: function( endPoint ){
            if (!self.endPoints[endPoint]) {
                // To avoid misleading errors
                throw ("Endpoint not found. \r\nEndpoint: " + endPoint + "\r\nFound: " + self.endPoints[endPoint]);
            }
            // reformat
            return globals.apiPath + self.endPoints[endPoint].replace(/{{([^}]+)}}/g, ":$1");
        }
};
```

I'm trying to write a `$resource` which uses this service, but the problem is when the service is injected into the factory, it has not yet been initialized and consequently calls to the method to retrieve the endpoint throw errors.

```
app.factory('providerFactory', ['$resource', 'preloader',

    function ($resource, preloader) {
        return $resource( "", null,
            {
                "getTypes" : {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: preloader.getResourceEndPoint('PROVIDER.LIST_TYPES')
                },

                "get": {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: preloader.getResourceEndPoint('PROVIDER.GET_PROVIDER_INFO'),
                    params: {
                        providerId: '@providerId'
                    }
                }
            }
        );
});
```

Error Msg:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROVIDER.LIST_TYPES' of undefined
    at Object.getResourceEndPoint (http://localhost:8888/client.git/build/app.min.js:3:8967)
```

If I step through the code, I see that the factory's `preloader.getResourceEndPoint()` calls are calling the service before the service has completed its initialization of the `endPointsList`.

What can I do to avoid this problem?  Do I have to use a `$q` promise?  It seems like overkill for something like this.  If so then I have to wonder if this is even the right approach to get something like this to work, but I'm not sure what approach to use.

I'm still learning AngularJS so I'm not entirely sure of the correct way to proceed.  Ive inherited this code so if it seems that it is convoluted/complicated for nothing, I'd appreciate insights on how to improve it.

Comment: I think you are confusing the two. Services don't return anything, the methods are placed on "this". Factories return an object. That said, I don't know if that will affect anything.

Comment: @ZackArgyle it should still works even if the service is written like that.

Comment: The `self.endPoints` is initialized asynchronously (wait for a http request to finished), and by the time `providerFactory` is initialized, the `endPoints` will still be empty. You have to rewrite your `providerFactory` to be asynchonous too.

Comment: @runTarm That's what I was figuring too, but not sure how to write the factory such that it is asynchronous.  Do I need to use a promise?  Can you provide a quick example/hint/suggestion how I can do this asynchronously please?

Comment: Can you provide the hash map with all the other page load resources and pass it into angular as a global variable? Seems a bit like a plane taking off without a flight plan

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure I understand.  How do I provide the hash map to bugler if I have to retrieve it via Ajax first?  Are you suggesting using something other thn ngular to retrieve it via Ajax?

Comment: Asking if you can't either pass it as JS variable to page or dynamically created script file in script tag. App would be able to make api calls immediately that way

Comment: @charlietfl - Not a bad idea, although not my ideal.  But it will definitely help get me further along, so might use that for the moment as I continue to look for other solutions.